# mystery mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm by no means experienced in mysql and keep getting an error in this lines of code:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO songs (unique_show_id, artist, date, year, city, state, venue, taper, transfered_by, source, mic_loc, lineage, uploaded_by, uploaded_on, show_notes, show_xml)
            VALUES('$showId', '$artist', '$showDate', '$year, '$city', '$state', '$venue', '$taper', '$transferer', '$source', '$mic_loc', '$lineage', '$uploader', NOW(), '$show_notes', '$show_xml')";    

//check to see if the query went through
            if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)){
              echo "query fail";
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
```

I'm sure it's something simplistic, but I can't see where the error is. The error message I get is:

```
query failError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ipuhgbi', 'CA', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'danwoods', NOW(), '', '<show id=\'gm198' at line 2
```

Some of the values I'm inserting are NULL, but from what I've read I don't think that should be a problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Show the replaced query.

Comment: Please post the output from `DESCRIBE SONGS` in MySQL so we can see what the data type(s) are for each column.

Answer (score 4):

Missing quote after `$year`.

When MySQL issues such an error (near bla di bla), the error is usually immediately before the string it mentions. In this case 'ipuhgbi' maps to $city, so you know it's right before '$city', and what do we see there? Voila, a missing quote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)** in each and every single one of your $variables.

**Also, [read this StackOverflow question carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain) regarding SQL Injections**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the last single quote on the error line is not escaped.

you need to remember to sanitize all of the strings going into the query.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite few things you need to be sure about:

1. You don't insert primary keys through queries (eg unique_show_id in your code)
2. For numbers you don't use single quotes.
3. It is better to use the set variant of inserting records which avoids count problems eg:
4. Use intval for numbers and mysql_real_escaps_string for strings to avoid injections issues as well as single quotes query erros.

   insert into table set field='field_value', field2='field_value' // and so on